# Communication with MySQL showing up as ESP in Wireshark

Tags: mysql, wireshark

I am trying to use wireshark to debug some network traffic between my machine and a remote mysql server. I downloaded [mysql_complete.pcap](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=mysql_complete.pcap) file and when I open it up in wireshark it shows as:

[image]

I also tried [mysql-ssl.pcapng](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=mysql-ssl.pcapng) and it shows up as:

[image]

but the communication between my machine and the remote mysql server is showing up as a cryptic ESP protocol:

[image]

Could anyone explain why and what can I do to inspect the traces as understandable MySQL

Answer (score 0):

This happened as the two machines were communicating over a secure VPN. I don't know if there is a way to convert the ESP messages into MySQL

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late. As mentioned by @morpheus, it appears that there is VPN here. So to capture the traffic in clear text, you should not select the standard network interface to sniff on, you can sniff on the VPN interface.